# Python script that creates multiple user accounts from an excel file in Ubuntu

Tags: python, excel, ubuntu, openpyxl

I'm trying to create a Python script that creates user accounts in Ubuntu from an excel file. The excel file contains:

**Full name**, an **username** and a **password**.

This is my code at the moment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import openpyxl
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

excel_file = os.open("Names_mod.xlsx", os.O_RDONLY)
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Names_mod.xlsx")
sheet = wb.active
max_row = sheet.max_row

for i in range(1, max_row + 1):
    name = sheet.cell(row = i, column = 1)
    addUser = "sudo useradd -m" + "name.value"
    os.system(addUser)
```

At the moment I'm just trying to create the user accounts without the password but I can't get it to work. Now it only creates one account from column 1, row 12 for some reason.

Anyone know what the problem could be? Would appreciate the help :)

Comment: shouldn't it be `addUser = "sudo useradd -m " + name.value`

Comment: That's true, thank you! It's still not creating all the users though :(

Comment: It's generally easier to use the `subprocess` module for running processes, but there is also the `shutil module for this kind of thing.

Comment: have you checked the indentation is right ? To me it appears the `os.system(addUser)` is outside the for loop

Comment: yes the indentation seems right